# How to define global types when code is wrapped in functions

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler, google-closure

This question is about using Google Closure Compiler's type annotations properly.

We have a convention that every javascript file is wrapped in a function. Example file:

`Square.js`:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    /**
     * @constructor
     */
    function Square() {};

    Square.prototype.draw = function() {
    };

}());
```

If we define a type (such as a constructor) inside this function, closure compiler is not aware of it in other files. For example, in another file:

`foo.js`:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    /** @param {Square} square */
    function drawSquare(square) {
        square.draw();
    }

}());
```

Compiling it with `-W VERBOSE` gives an error that the type `Square` is not defined:

```
foo.js:4: WARNING - Bad type annotation. Unknown type Square
        /** @type {Square} square */
                   ^

0 error(s), 1 warning(s), 83.3% typed
```

We've created externs for all our classes, in separate files, to work around this. Creating externs is a bad solution because now we have to maintain two files for every class.

1. Is it possible to share the types if files are wrapped by a file-level function?
2. What's the recommended way of working with closure in general for sharing types between files? Does using closure library provide/require help in any way?

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/closure-library/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions

Comment: @epascarello, how does that answer the question?

Comment: Did you not see the heading "*When I compile with type-checking on, I get warnings about "Bad type annotation. Unknown type" from closure library files.*"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you can manage to have it work by exporting the symbol with the name you want to use outside the restricted scope of the enclosing function. Something like this:

```
(function() {
    goog.provide('Square');
    //'use strict';

    /**
     * @constructor
     */
    function Square() {};

    Square.prototype.draw = function() {
      return "\\o/";
    };
    goog.exportSymbol('Square', Square);
}());
```

However, I think your problem is here:

> We have a convention that every javascript file is wrapped in a function.

Closure has a different convention, which is to [define namespaces](https://developers.google.com/closure/library/docs/introduction).

To answer your second question, the recommended closure way is:

```
goog.provide('my.Square');
/**
 * @constructor
 */
my.Square = function() {
};

my.Square.prototype.draw = function() {
  // TODO
};
```

and:

```
goog.provide('my.App');

goog.require('my.Square');


/**
 * @param {my.Square} square The square to draw
 */
my.App.prototype.drawSquare = function(square) {
  square.draw();
};
```

Comment: I recommend you read the [Closure book](http://books.google.ch/books?id=p7uyWPcVGZsC)

Comment: thanks - I'll take a closer look at using goog.provide/require and working with namespaces. My only concern with that book is that it's 4 years old by now.

Comment: also - the reason for the file-level function wrapping is to be able to place 'strict mode' statements without risking affecting any non-strict third-party code that we depend on (and don't compile); and to have it turned on in development (where we don't use closure's output). So I don't know how we could use the namespaces conventions with that in mind.

Comment: @sinelaw The book is still very valid. You might also want to use `goog.scope` to satisfy your requirements.